# In WordSmith jquery, what determins location of link icon after double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented the amazing WordSmith jquery plug-in and it works, but for some reason I loose my question mark icon; i.e. it is offset to the lower right instead of on top of the selected word. This can be found at http://dev.thediabetesnetwork.com/diabetes-articles/

I don't want to jump in and start hacking up the code before checking with the community. The WordSmith is located at http://getwordsmith.co/

Comment: Hi Shane - I am the co-creator of Wordsmith. I'll take a look and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, great idea btw. As a side note, this is a joomla site, very heavy with script due to many plugins, so could be a conflict on my end.

Comment: Shane: Please load the site you provided a link to and check your console.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I noticed the conflict (two errors) with the jquery file, it was not coming up except as a warning in my other tool so I guess it pays to use the better options. I will look at options on maybe a no-conflict? I am still learning how to debug javascript and 20+ script files on one page does not help.

Comment: @RichardHollis EDIT: I fixed the errors, but still have the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shane - I have modified the Wordsmith code. Please try this modified version (see link below) to see if it fixes your problem. I need to do further testing but assuming it works ok for you and tests OK then this will be in the next release.

Download wordsmith.js from here:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0MCUii-LndWRFpwMXQzcFlSSzQ

Comment: You can check it out to see if doing everything you want, but suits my needs. Thank you for such a fast response!

Comment: Hey, no worries. Thanks for using Wordsmith! I can see it's all working ok now on your site. Thanks for marking as answer. This change will be fed back into the product very shortly, as others will no doubt hit a similar problem.